# Inherit vbYesNo response from a module to another

Tags: vba

**Hi Everyone**

I am doing a macro with 4 different modules.
The first 3 modules are for formatting different files, while I will click Module 4 if I want to format all the files at once.
There is a message box for the 1st 3 modules containing summary report of the formatting, however, I don't want to open those message box if I call the modules thru module 4.

Below is my code but it is not working since the value of Summary(response to vbYesNo) is not transfered to Module 1 :(

Module 4 code:

```
Sub FormatAll_Click()
YesNo = MsgBox("Do you want to show Report Summary after formatting each CSA  Report?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Report Summary")
Summary = YesNo

Module1.FORMAT_1st_Report

Module2.FORMAT_2nd_Report

Module3.FORMAT_3rd_Report

MsgBox "Done formatting all documents", vbInformation, "Done"

End Sub
```

Module 1 code:

```
If Summary <> vbNo Then
    MsgBox "Done Formatting Purchasing Document Creation Report" & vbNewLine & "Summary:" & vbNewLine & "     Successful: " & s & vbNewLine & "     Empty Worksheet: " & e & vbNewLine & "     Failed: " & f, vbInformation, "SUMMARY REPORT"
    If s > 0 Then
        Dim YesNo As String
        YesNo = MsgBox("Do you want to open all successfully formatted file?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Open File")
        If YesNo = vbYes Then
        Module14.OpenPOCreation
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an optional parameter with a default value of 0 to your other Sub(s) and pass `Summary` from `FormatAll_Click`.

E.g. -

```
Sub FormatAll_Click()
    Dim Summary

    Summary = MsgBox("Do you want to show Report Summary after formatting" & _
                 " each CSA  Report?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Report Summary")

    Module1.FORMAT_1st_Report Summary
    Module2.FORMAT_2nd_Report Summary
    Module3.FORMAT_3rd_Report Summary

    MsgBox "Done formatting all documents", vbInformation, "Done"

End Sub


Sub FORMAT_1st_Report(Optional response = 0)
    If response = vbYes Then
        MsgBox "Called with vbYes"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not called with vbYes"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is really helpful :)